# trigger an animation on button press

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, task, mvvm-light

I am trying to figure out how to trigger an animation from my viewmodel in my MVVM Xamarin Forms application using the MVVM light framework without crashing my app.

I have learned that animations do not belong in the viewmodel and therefore I moved this logic to the view.

When a button is pressed (bound to a command in my viewmodel) I send a message from my viewmodel to my view to trigger the animation.

Viewmodel Code:

```
public class GamePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

    public ICommand NextRoundCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                NextButtonEnabled = false;
                _game.MoveToNextRound();
                UpdateOnScreenText();
                NextButtonEnabled = true;
            },()=> false);
        }
    }

    private bool _nextButtonEnabled = false;
    public bool NextButtonEnabled
    {
        get { return _nextButtonEnabled; }
        set
        {
            _nextButtonEnabled = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(()=>NextButtonEnabled);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateOnScreenText()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new StartEnlargeAnimationMessage());
        Item1Text = _game.CurrentRound.OpenCards[0].Name;
    }
}
```

In the code behind of my xaml view I have a method that performs the animation.

View Code:

```
public partial class GamePage : ContentPage
{
    public GamePage(GamePageViewModel gamePageViewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = gamePageViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();

        Messenger.Default.Register<StartEnlargeAnimationMessage>(this, PlayEnlargeAnimation);
    }

    //private bool playingAnimation = false;
    private async void PlayEnlargeAnimation(StartEnlargeAnimationMessage message)
    {
        await RoundLabel.ScaleTo(2, 500, Easing.CubicIn);
        await RoundLabel.ScaleTo(1, 500, Easing.CubicIn);
    }
```

This works somewhat.

The problem is that when a user taps the button twice (fast, within the active animation) I get an error "An attempt was made to transition a task to a final state when it had already completed."

This problem seems to be a known issue for many months but is not yet fixed (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41016).

As suggested in the comments of this bugreport the ways I have tried to work around this is to try and hide / disable the button but not yet found a successfull way of doing this.

I also tried to call the animation synchronously.

If you have any insight in how to fix this scenario it would be greatly appreciated.

My (still small) codebase can be found here: https://github.com/sjorsmiltenburg/Cyclades.Shuffler/tree/develop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm.. apparently I was looking at old code in my emulator. I had to uninstall the program on my emulator for it to refresh. After doing so disabling / enabling the buttons during the animation fixed my problem. Although I am still dissapointed that this could crash the application.